# Arrow keys to move across textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to move cursor on click of keyboard arrow keys. In general we use **Tab** to move cursor, but instead of that I want to use the arrow keys to move cursor inside the different textbox. 
[image]

On keyboard Arrow Right key press I want to move from username to password textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try TextBox KeyDown event

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Down:
            //your code
            break;
        case Keys.Left:
            //your code
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            //your code
            break;
        case Keys.Up:
            //your code
            break;
        default:
            //your code
            break;
    }
}
```